# Build .NET Core 2.0 on Travis CI

Tags: .net-core, travis-ci, .net-core-2.0

I migrated my tests and demos projects to .NET Core 2.0. I tried to build this project but I have this error:

> /home/travis/build/MarkKhromov/The-Log/TheLog.Demos/TheLog.Demos.csproj.metaproj
>   : error MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded. Could not find
>   file
>   '/home/travis/build/MarkKhromov/The-Log/TheLog.Demos/TheLog.Demos.csproj.metaproj

I wrote this in the .travis.yml:

```
language: csharp
mono: none
dotnet: 2.0.0
script:
  - dotnet restore
  - dotnet build ./TheLog.sln
  - dotnet test ./TheLog.Tests/
```

What did I do wrong? Locally the build is fine.

Comment: You are required to post your code here, not a third party site which can change or disappear tomorrow: [mcve]

Comment: @Rob hi! Okay, I edit my post now, thx!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem as follows:
I wrote in the .travis.yml:

```
language: csharp
mono: none
dotnet: 2.0.0
script:
  - dotnet restore
  - dotnet build ./TheLog/
  - dotnet build ./TheLog.Demos/
  - dotnet test ./TheLog.Tests/
```

But for me it still remains a mystery why these errors occurred when I tried to compile a solution (.sln) file

Comment: I had the same issue when building with JetBrains Rider. Building with CLI worked though.